# How to fix this script?

Tags: javascript

Im trying to run the script bellow and it gives ans error: game.js:35 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'classList' of undefined
        at HTMLDivElement. (game.js:35)

```
the error happens right here : allNumbers[i].classList.remove("show");

var numberOfCircles = 9;
var rangeOfNumbers =1000;
var circles = document.querySelectorAll(".circle-number");
var generateRandomNumbers =[];
/*var pickedNumber = pickNumber();*/
var messageToDisplay = document.querySelector(".guess-number");
var krug = document.querySelectorAll(".circle");
var numberToGuess;
var numberPosition;
var counter=0;
var allNumbers= document.querySelectorAll(".show");

randomNumbers(numberOfCircles,rangeOfNumbers);
randomNumberToDisplay();
compareNumbers();
reset();



function compareNumbers(){
    for (var i=0; i < allNumbers.length; i++){
        krug[i].addEventListener("click", function(){
            allNumbers[i].classList.remove("show");
            counter +=1;        
            if(Number(circles.textContent) ==numberToGuess){
                circles.style.color ="green";
                alert("You guessed right from" + counter+" try")
            } else {
              this.style.color ="red";
            }
        })
    }
}
```

Comment: does `allNumbers` definitely have elements in it?

Comment: allNumbers[i] - do something like add alert(typeof( allNumbers[i]))

Comment: Hello @Artur. Try to be more specific o your question and pinpoint where the error is happening. That might call more attention from people wanting to help.

Comment: @Artur Nurbaev you are calling two more functions `randomNumberToDisplay();` and `randomNumbers` before `randomNumbers`. Maybe you are changing `allNumbers` in those functions

Comment: Also FYI: You are adding listeners - but do you ever remove them?

Comment: Hi @Nick , yes it has when run console.log(AllNumbers) it gives me  array with 9 elements: NodeList(9). But when i run for loop with i from 0 to 8 it fails.

Comment: @JGFMK ,  for example console.log(AllNumbers[1]) gives result.

Comment: Hi @lucrib. it happens in this line  :allNumbers[i].classList.remove("show") of the compareNumbers() function

Comment: @ JGFMK im adding listener to the <div> to remove .show class from it. So what i want is to loop through array of divs and from each one when clicked to remove class .show

Answer (score 0):

In commpareNumbers, add this before the for loop:

```
if (allNumbers === undefined) {
  return
}
```

undefined is probably resulting  when

```
var allNumbers= document.querySelectorAll(".show");
```

returns no results.

Comment: allNumbers definitely has a array with 9 elements. It shows through console.log. When i try to loop through it it gives error of undefined